# Diferencia de salida en ejecución de comando Bash con terminal o con Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, gpu

Buenas noches comunidad.

Estoy ejecutando un comando Bash a traves de python con subprocess.popen y la salida que recibo es diferente a la que obtengo si lo ejecuto a través del terminal bash. Remito a continuación el código del script en python y las salidas que obtengo tanto en Bash como en python.

La verdad, me ha sorprendido bastante... ¿Quizá tenga que ver con el split que le realizo al comando? Según he visto, esa es la manera idónea de hacerlo, pero ni idea, soy nuevo en bash.

Código Python:

```
import subprocess

bashCommand = r"lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1 | xargs -i lspci -v -s {}"
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
x = output.splitlines()
```

Salida en la terminal de Linux:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT215 [GeForce GT 240] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GT215 [GeForce GT 240]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

Imagen de salida de las variables en python:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar, python me devuelve muchos mas valores, lo cual no está mal, pero no es precisamente lo que busco.

Un saludo, muchas gracias!! ;)

Comment: He comprobado que si que encuentra lo que busco también, con el identificador 01:00.0, pero solo me pone la cabecera, nada mas.

Comment: Correcto, según me temo, parece ser que solo coge la primera palabra del string al hacerle el split... Bueno, muchas gracias! Esto está ya cerrado

Answer (score 0):

Estoy un poco tonto... Evidentemente, al realizar el split, solo cogia la primera parte de la lista, y si no realizaba el split, no me dejaba por los caracteres especiales... Tengo la consola de Spyder en castellano y no entiendo muy los mensajes de error que me devuelve, a ver si la configuro en inglés...

Muchas gracias! ;)